# android-studio auto enable button after the text-field filled with voice recognition

Tags: android, arraylist

I have created an Android application by using voice recognition and works great, it displays what the user said. But I want to set a listener for the text field. For example, if I say Mumbai then it will redirect into the Mumbai page without clicking submit button.

Can you do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: at the point, where you set a text to your text field, just check which text you set, and do what you want with it.